# Trigger to get Names of all contacts on Account field

Tags: trigger, triggercontext

I need to write a trigger in which all the related contacts names should be shown on Account field.
If I have 3 contacts of an Account, they should come like this:
Smith, John, Brutus.
I am doing this way...

```
trigger ContactNamesOnAccount on Contact (after update, after insert) 
{    
   String names;
   Set<id> accIdList = new Set<id>();
   for(Contact con : Trigger.new)
   {
    accIdList.add(con.accountid);
   }

   List<Account> accUpdateList = new List<Account>();
   for(Account acc : [Select id, name, Contact_Names__c, 
                             (Select Id, name From Contacts) 
                        From Account Where Id In : accIdList])
   {
       for(Contact con : acc.contacts)
       {
        if(con.lastname != null)
        {
            names = names + ', ' + con.lastname;
        }
        acc.Contact_Names__c = names;
    }    
     accUpdateList.add(acc);
   }    
   update accUpdateList;
}
```

Comment: where is your inner query ? and also names string initialize inside Account for else it will contain the all prev account values as well

Comment: What is your actual output vs your expected output?

Comment: @sfdcweb I have added inner query now...but now Its showing null,test,test1..I have only 2 contacts test and test1

Comment: @sfdcweb I have edited my code...but null is coming....

Comment: Because it is taking the "names" variable as null and it is appending the Contacts next

Comment: @Anzar when you initialize `String names;` this is null that the reason .. initiliaze like `String names = '';`

Comment: done now its working thanx man :)

Comment: @Anzar cool.. one more thing you need to initialize this `String names = '';` inside Account for loop so for each Account new string should get prepared..

Comment: @sfdcweb thanx man (Y)...

Comment: @sfdcweb there is more thing I want to ask , is coming before the first contact how could I rectify this...

Comment: @sfdcweb contacts are coming like :  , Test , test1
comma is coming before first contact name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many errors in your code

1. sub Query contacts
2. Initialize your names string with blank
3. Add your names variable inside for loop and prepare string like below snippet

Use String join method here so you need to collect all the contact lastName in list and pass in `String.join` function

check **[Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_join)**

```
for(Account acc : [Select id, name, Contact_Names__c, 
                             (Select Id, name, LastName From Contacts) 
                        From Account Where Id In : accIdList])
{
    List<String> lstSrting = new List<String>();
    for(Contact con : acc.contacts)
    {
        lstSrting.add(con.lastname);
    }
    acc.Contact_Names__c = String.join(lstSrting, ',');
}
```

Comment: @Anzar How can this works when you are referencing `con.lastname` which is not selected in query `(Select Id, name From Contacts)` may you tell me?

Comment: @sfdcweb How you can re-declare a variable  `List<String> lstSrting = new List<String>();`?

Comment: @sfdcweb Do you really have a field named `name` for contact object?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 yeah that just missed in query .. now updated.. OP can use contact's name or last name field either or then that is OP choice

Comment: @sfdcweb what about the variable creation in loop iteration `List<String> lstSrting = new List<String>();`?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 yes so if there is 2 different Account execute in trigger context then for each account list should contain only Account's related contact name... let me know if this make sense

Comment: If you have list you can `add` items to it and can `clear` it when you want to use the same again for new data items what you say?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 it's totally depends on your choice if you want to clear the list or initialize inside for loop. it is reinitialize each time and prepare new list.. For me best option to initialize the list inside for loop instead make the list clear and again add into list..

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your code. Try this one out.

```
  trigger ContactNamesOnAccount on Contact (after update, after insert) 
    {    
       String names='';
       Integer ok=1;
       Set<id> accIdList = new Set<id>();
       for(Contact con : Trigger.new)
       {
          if(con.accountid!=null)
           accIdList.add(con.accountid);
       }

       List<Account> accUpdateList = new List<Account>();
       for(Account acc : [Select id, name, Contact_Names__c, (Select Id, name From Contacts) From Account Where Id In : accIdList])
       {
           ok=1;
           for(Contact con : acc.contacts)
           {    

              if(con.name!=null)
              {
               if(ok==1)
               {
                names = con.name;
                ok=0; 
               }

               else
                {
                names = names  + ',' + con.name;
                }

             }

           }
         acc.Contact_Names__c = names;
         accUpdateList.add(acc);
       }    
       update accUpdateList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ;)

```
trigger ContactNamesOnAccount on Contact (after update, after insert) {    
  Set<id> accIdList = new Set<id>();
  for(Contact con : Trigger.new){
    accIdList.add(con.accountid);
  }

  List<Account> accUpdateList = new List<Account>();
  List<String> names = new List<String>;

  for(Account acc : [Select id, Contact_Names__c, (Select LastName From Contacts) From Account Where Id In : accIdList]){
    for(Contact con : acc.contacts){
      if(con.LastName != null){
        /* add name to list */
        names.add(con.LastName);
      }
    }

    /* update name separating ', '  */
    acc.Contact_Names__c = String.join(names, ', ');;
    accUpdateList.add(acc);

    /* clear list to add new account contact names */
    names.clear();
  }    
  update accUpdateList;
}
```

You missed to query `LastName` field of contact and need to clear `names` for every account contacts;