# How to add the last name of contact to account custom field Summary so that all the names are separated by a ';'

Tags: apex, trigger

rigger ContactNamesOnAccount on Contact (after insert)
   {
      String names='';
      Integer flag=1;
      Set accIdList = new Set();

```
  for(Contact con : Trigger.new)
  {
     if(con.accountid!=null)
      accIdList.add(con.accountid);
  }       List<Account> accUpdateList = new List<Account>();
for(Account acc : [Select id, name, Summary__c,(Select Id, name, LastName From Contacts) 
                                               From Account Where Id In : accIdList])

         {
               List<String> lstSrting = new List<String>();
        for(Contact con : acc.contacts)
                {
                    lstSrting.add(con.lastname);
                }
          if (String.isBlank(acc.Summary__c)) 
           {
                 acc.Summary__c = String.join(lstSrting, ' ;');
           } 
             else 
           {
               acc.Summary__c += String.join(lstSrting, ' ;');
           }
               accUpdateList.add(acc);
        }      
    update accUpdateList;
  }
```

Comment: In my code im able to add the names int the summary feild but the contacts  are not getting created in the contact object

Comment: Explain more clearly what your problem is i.e. what you mean by "the contacts are not getting created in the contact object".

Comment: I did not realize until writing an answer that you copied and pasted code from [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118327/trigger-to-get-names-of-all-contacts-on-account-field), but did not use the accepted answer. That code is *not* a good source, as described in Ratan Paul's excellent answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger to get Names of all contacts on Account field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118327/trigger-to-get-names-of-all-contacts-on-account-field)

Comment: @KeithC The contact record isn't getting created. It says the record was deleted but the last name from the lastname field gets populated in the aacount Summary__c field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you begin looping over your Account query, you should not then iterate over `Trigger.new` again in an inner `for` loop. That's why you performed a Contact subquery: you should be looping over `acc.Contacts` to collect last names for *this* Account, since `Trigger.new` has Contacts for all of the Accounts involved.

It would be much cleaner, instead of the way you've implemented concatenation of the Contacts' last names, to add them to a `List<String>`. Then, you can assign the value like this:

```
if (String.isBlank(acc.Summary__c)) {
   acc.Summary__c = String.join(listOfLastNames, ';');
} else {
    acc.Summary__c += String.join(listOfLastNames, ';');
}
```

Lastly, it would be a much simpler and more complete solution to implement this using Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries, a free and open source product. DLRS automatically handles inserts, updates, deletions, and merges for you, the latter three of which you are not handling here.

Comment: can you plz edit my code . Im actually new to apex programming.

Comment: Naveen, welcome to the Salesforce platform and SFSE. This site is a very useful one for learning, but there's also some specific expectations about what kinds of questions and answers get posted here. The [Help Center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help)'s How to Ask section is a great resource. One thing that is typical throughout SFSE is that you won't have code written for you. Instead, try to ask well-defined, narrow questions that can be given a specific answer in text, not in new code.

Comment: in my code im having only one problem that the contact details are not getting inserted in the contact object .Do i need to write a insert statement for that?